# How do you say: "it could have been avoided" The correct way?

Tags: verbs, phrases, past

I tried, but ended up with this:

それは避けられたかもしれない。

But, I do not know if it is right to say it that way

Comment: What context is it used in?

Answer (score 4):

> It could have been avoided.
>   それは避けられたかもしれない。

You are right.

1. それは避けられたはずなのに、実際には避けられなかった。
2. それは避けられたはずなのに。
3. それは避けられたのに。
4. それは避けられた**の**かもしれません。
5. それは避けられたかもしれません。
6. それは避けられた**の**かもしれない。
7. それは避けられたかもしれない。 - Your answer

Though sentence 5 and 7 are commonly used, I think, sentence 4 and 6 are more natural than sentence 5 and 7 respectively.